# dealing with a file path argument: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby

I am writing a short ruby script that takes a file as an argument and then parses that file.
I have put together a few conditions in the initialize method to ensure that a file path exists and it is readable and if it nots it prints an error message to the user.

However when I run the file with out a file attached along side the message "please add log file path". I also receive the following error messages.

```
please add log file path
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from webserver_log_parser.rb:41:in `<main>'
    2: from webserver_log_parser.rb:41:in `new'
    1: from webserver_log_parser.rb:6:in `initialize'
webserver_log_parser.rb:6:in `exist?': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

I would be really grateful if someone could explain why this happens and a way to fix this issue.

````
  def initialize(log_file_path = nil)
    puts 'please add log file path' unless log_file_path
    puts 'Could not find the file path' unless File.exist?(log_file_path)
    puts '${log_file_path} is unreadable' unless File.readable?(log_file_path)
    extract_log_file(log_file_path)
  end

  def extract_log_file(log_file_path)
    webpages = Hash.new { |url, ip_address| url[ip_address] = [] }
    File.readlines(log_file_path).each do |line|
      url, ip_address = line.split
      webpages[url] << ip_address
    end
    sort_results(webpages)
  end

  def sort_results(results)
    total_views = {}
    unique_views = {}
    results.each do |url, ip_address|
      total_views[url] = ip_address.length
      unique_views[url] = ip_address.uniq.length
    end
    display_results(total_views, unique_views)
  end

  def display_results(views, unique_views)
    puts 'The most viewed pages are as follows:'
    total_views_sorted = views.sort_by { |_k, count| -count }
    total_views_sorted.each { |key, count| puts "#{key} #{count}" }
    puts 'The pages with the most unique views are as follows:'
    unique_sort = unique_views.sort_by { |_k, count| -count }
    unique_sort.each { |key, count| puts "#{key} #{count}" }
  end
end

if $PROGRAM_NAME == __FILE__
  LogParser.new(ARGV[0])
end```
````

Comment: Your error message contains line numbers 41 and 6. Which lines correspond to that in the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your guard conditions are triggered, you need to stop further processing (no need to check for readability of a file at `file_path` if you already established that `file_path` is nil). It could look like this, for example:

```
def initialize(log_file_path = nil)
  unless log_file_path
    puts 'please add log file path' 
    return
  end
  unless File.exist?(log_file_path)
    puts 'Could not find the file path' 
    return
  end
  unless File.readable?(log_file_path)
    puts '${log_file_path} is unreadable' 
    return
  end

  extract_log_file(log_file_path)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly terminate the script with a message, you can use `abort`.

```
def initialize(log_file_path = nil) 
    abort("please add log file path") unless log_file_path
    abort("Could not find the file path") unless File.exist?(log_file_path)
    abort("${log_file_path} is unreadable") unless File.readable?(log_file_path)
    extract_log_file(log_file_path)
end
```